# Problem in python using cx_freeze, error finding file

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I created a python program using tkinter and cx_freeze and it is working perfectly on my pc, but when I run it on my father's pc it doesn't open, it just shows an error saying ImportError: DLL load failed, and another thing I noticed was that on his pc it's showing my user from my windows and not his, as if I were looking for the file on my pc and not on his, what do i do?

Comment: What OSes are installed on both computers? Are they both 64/32bit? Can you please post the full error message?